# Javascript Looping over an array of object and adding eventListener has a weird behavior

Tags: javascript, closures

I don't understand a concept in Javascript. First of all, I created an arrow function init() which loops over an array of object and initialize an image tag on which an eventListener is attached.

```
init: () => {
        let catsContainer = document.getElementById('catsContainer')
        for (let cat of data.cats) {
            let element = `<img src="img/${cat.image}" catName="${cat.name}" alt="catImage" id="catOneImage" width="50" height="50">`;
            element = octopus.htmlToElement(element)
            catsContainer.appendChild(element)
            element.addEventListener('click', ((elementCopy) => {
                return () => {
                    view.loadImage(elementCopy)
                }
            })(element));
        }
    }
```

on click of that image, a new big image is loaded (the src attribute is changed) via the loadImage() function.

```
loadImage: function (el) {
        let catBigImage = document.getElementById('catBigImage');
        let catName = document.getElementById('catName');
        catBigImage.setAttribute('src', el.getAttribute('src'))
        catName.innerHTML = el.getAttribute('catName')
        catBigImage.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let obj = data.cats.find(o => o.name === el.getAttribute('catName'));
            console.log(`obj:: ${obj}`)
            octopus.incrementCounter(obj)
            console.log(obj)
        });
    }
```

And normally when you click on that big image, the selected object's count property must be incremented. The problem is that when a new image is loaded, my code keeps the last loaded object and also increments its counter. I don't really understand this behavior till now.[image]

You can see on the uploaded screenshot that at the third click on new loaded image (cat4), my code also increments the last loaded one (cat2) which result in 4 console.log lines.

Comment: That's because `addEventListener` doesn't *replace* the listener, it *adds* it. So you are accumulating event handlers on the same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because this code:

```
    catBigImage.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let obj = data.cats.find(o => o.name === el.getAttribute('catName'));
        console.log(`obj:: ${obj}`)
        octopus.incrementCounter(obj)
        console.log(obj)
    });
```

...*adds* an event handler every time it gets executed. It does not *replace* the previously bound event handler.

You should move this code out of the `loadImage` function, and only execute it once.

As a rule of thumb, it is a code smell when an event listener is added inside a function that handles an event.

Comment: Thank you @trincot. I will try it and make the answer accepted if it works.

Comment: it works like a charm and thanks to your advice, i think my code is now more structured.